# getting error when doing registarion in pushwoosh

Tags: android, pushwoosh

**Pushwoosh android error:**

[RequestManager] ERROR: https:woosh.com/json/1.3/registerDevice
com.pushwoosh.internal.network.b: https://.api.pushwoosh.com/json/1.3/registerDevice
at com.pushwoosh.internal.network.e.a(Unknown Source:269)
at com.pushwoosh.internal.network.e.a(Unknown Source:1)
at com.pushwoosh.internal.network.e$b.a(Unknown Source:20)
at com.pushwoosh.internal.network.e$b.doInBackground(Unknown Source:2)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2021-02-23 17:44:38.358 3420-3420/com.thehealthymummy E/Pushwoosh: [DeviceRegistrar] Registration error: https://.api.pushwoosh.com/json/1.3/registerDevice

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not set your Pushwoosh application id correctly during SDK integration.

You need to add application id to AndroidManifest.xml

See the step 7 here:
https://docs.pushwoosh.com/platform-docs/pushwoosh-sdk/android-push-notifications/firebase-integration/integrate-pushwoosh-android-sdk

Comment: I added pushwoosh_app_id in AndroidManifestfile

Answer (score 0):

**issue fixed:**
The issue was on pushwoosh backend. Your account had an old type of subscription plan, and, after canceling, it was downgraded to a basic plan with no restrictions applied. We've adjusted restrictions to match the current StartUp plan, so it should be fine now.